# Why does __func__ return <unknown> in some functions in C?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, func

I have many different functions, and they all have simple `printf` statements using `__func__` similar to this one:

`printf("%s - hello world!", __func__);`

Now the problem I am running into is that in some functions it returns `<unknown>` instead of the function name.

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? AFAIK `__func__` is a part of `c99` so I don't understand why it isn't working as advertised.

I am using GCC 4.7.2 in Debian.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) I am wondering if it is similar to this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65294 so maybe it is a problem with a header being included.

Comment: Could you show us a pertinant case ?

Comment: Could it be you are building different modules using different gcc options for C compatibility?

Comment: I imagine all functions are not in the same .c, maybe a .h included which undefined __func__

Comment: > nouney&Shafik Yaghmour: Sorry can't really share the code itself. I will play around with it a bit. Come to think of it, Mali's suggestion could be the answer... Will update the question with what I find.

Comment: @c00kiemonster Since it is coming back as `<unknown>` it is not being undefined but defined differently a quick test would be to use `__FUNCTION__` in a section of the code where `__func__` does not work and then you know most likely that some header is doing something like `define __func__ "<unknown>"`

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That was it, when I used __FUNCTION__ it worked fine. If you make that a proper answer I will select it as the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a header you are including must be doing something similar to this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65294) and defining `__func__` as follows:

```
define __func__ "<unknown>"
```

and so you only see it when you include that header(s). A quick way to test for this would be to use `__FUNCTION__` in a section of the code where `__func__` does not work. Then you need to narrow it down and figure out which header has the troublesome logic and fix it.